# vwmare linux - ubuntu 22.04 / No Wired Connection in network settings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

I restarted my VMWare and lost connection to internet out of the blue.

I'm pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu. It gave me a pretty lengthy .log file which is above limits allowed here.

Is there anything I can do? Most commands I found on google seem not to work - either something is missing or wrong naming.

Anyways, I opened a new version of Ubuntu on my VMWare and everything works fine. However I have a bit of stuff saved on the original version, and if it's possible I'd like to continue working on the original installation.

Is there anything I should add to help figure out this problem?
The log's might be hard to post here unfortunately?
If not, where can I ask for help ?

Comment: Change your guest VM to Bridged temporarily and see if it gets internet this way.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for leaving a comment. I did play around with the network adapter network conncetion settings and switched the options from NAT to Bridged and even tried all the other ones. However that did not help.

Comment: Save your VM and try reinstalling VMware.  No issue here with VMware at all.